# IPv6: the end of NAT?

Tags: nat, ipv6, ipv4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch to IPv6 and get rid of NAT? Are you kidding?](https://serverfault.com/questions/184524/switch-to-ipv6-and-get-rid-of-nat-are-you-kidding)

Is NAT going to disappear with IPv6? What about during the "transition" from IPv4-IPv6?

How are we all going to access the internet then?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/184524/switch-to-ipv6-and-get-rid-of-nat-are-you-kidding