# Linux IPv6 Transparent Proxy (but Linux doesn't support NAT on IPv6!?)

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, ipv6, transparent-proxy

On Linux I can make a transparent proxy simply by adding a `iptables -j REDIRECT` command.

To my surprise, I am needing to support IPv6. Simple enough right? `iptables6 -j REDIRECT` *command not supported!?*

Apparently, Linux threw out NAT (and transparent proxy support with it) on IPv6. I don't care much about NAT on IPv6. **So how do people get a squid transparent proxy working on IPv6?** With Linux as the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First give it a read on this [answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/184524/switch-to-ipv6-and-get-rid-of-nat-are-you-kidding/184535#184535). You will have to configure your firewall and use other means to provide proxying like automatic configuration. IPV6 doesn't provide any NAT so there's no interception of traffic, ergo no transparent proxying.

Squid wiki has a [Tproxy patch](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4) but seems like a hack to me, you can try but I never tested.

Other solutions likes [WCCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Cache_Communication_Protocol) from CISCO were also very connected to ipv4 and will not work on ipv6, but probably will be updated (or something will show up to replace).

Comment: +1 and Answer for suggesting TPROXY netfilter/iptables TARGET.

Comment: How is Tproxy a hack? It is native to Linux 2.6.37 and newer. It is the only way to do transparent proxying with IPv6 on Linux.

Comment: @unixman it's a hack because you are not supposed to do transparent proxying on ipv6 :)

Comment: then how would you implement content filtering on IPv6?

Comment: @unixman using a normal proxy, why does it have to be transparent?

Comment: @coredump: Because transparent "Just Works" while automatic proxy only sometimes works and the users think the internet is broken.