# Again trouble with IPv6

Tags: ipv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does IPv6 subnetting work and how does it differ from IPv4 subnetting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting)

I have a IPv4-Subnet (/28) and a IPv6-Subnet (/64) - lets say the IPv4 Subnet is "87.240.70.144/28" and the IPv6 one is "2001:1095:10:61::/64" - now I want to give every Server with a IPv4-Address an IPv6 as well. I've heard that it's a good value to do it like this:

Server1:
 * 87.240.70.146
 * 2001:1608:10:61::146

is this possible like this - and would you suggest this way?
Whats the greatest number (at the last position) wich is possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, and it is used quite frequently, since it makes it easier for admins to remember addresses.

The "biggest number" (counting only the last position) is:

```
2001:1608:10:61::FFFF # or
2001:1608:10:61::9999 # if you use only decimal numbers in the last quad
```

The biggest address in your pool is ofcourse:

```
2001:1608:10:61:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF
```

Depending on what you find to be the "biggest" in your numbering scheme

Answer (score 3):

That is certainly a possible way of numbering your servers. `2001:1095:10:61::/64` contains all addresses from `2001:1095:0010:0061:0000:0000:0000:0000` to `2001:1095:0010:0061:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`, so `2001:1608:10:61::146` (which is the same as `2001:1608:0010:0061:0000:0000:0000:0146`) is possible.

There are many ways to number devices on the network, and the way you describe makes sense if you want to keep IPv4 and IPv6 addresses aligned. I use the same structure in many data centres myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help - now it's more clear! - Only to be sure - after 9999 - it would start with aaaa right?

Comment: It's a plain 16-bit hexadecimal number, so after 9999 come 999a, 999b, 999c, ..., 999f, 99a0, etc.