# What's the difference between a subnet and a netblock?

Tags: networking, subnet

I'm new to networking and am trying to get my terminology straight. I've Google this question but haven't found anything that clearly explains it.

Comment: Can you add a bit more information about what exactly you are not sure about? I have never come across the term "netblock".

Comment: @MarkoPolo Have you tried googling it? I think its shorthand for network block.

Comment: Yes I Googled it and there are very few references to the term. Definitely not a common term which is why I was curious about context.

Comment: Is network block more common?

Comment: In what context? What are you trying to describe?

Comment: https://youtu.be/e-AoilQ8v6o?t=8

Comment: Thanks for the link - that clarifies things. In the content of that video, a netblock and subnet are two words for the same thing. To be honest I think the author of that video is slightly confusing his terms as it does appear that Netblock is more commonly used to describe IP address blocks assigned to organisations (as per EEAA's answer below).

Comment: We have two canonical answers with regards to subnets: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work and the IPv6 companion http://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting

Comment: True, but neither of those posts explains the word "netblock".  I agree with EEAA's answer (perhaps the question could be cleaned up a bit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is an official definition of "netblock", but in common usage, I've most frequently heard it used in reference to an IP address allocation assigned by an [RIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) to another organization.

"Subnet", on the other hand, is a more broad networking concept, used when referring to a portion of the IP addresses that are part of a larger network scope.

So, to use these terms together, I will use this fictitious situation:

- [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/) has allocated the `203.0.113.0/24` netblock to MyBigCorporation
- MyBigCorporation needs to subdivide this allocation into smaller subnets for various purposes, so...
- MyBigCorporation allocates `203.0.113.0/28` (a subnet of `203.0.113.0/24`) for use by their inbound MXes

Comment: This is as I understand it in a MSO context.

Answer (score 1):

A word about the word subnet:

The word subnet is, IMO, incorrectly used most of the time from a purely technical definition. What people generally refer to as a subnet is actually just a network. A subnet is when you take a network and divide it into smaller networks, hence subnetworks, or subnets.

If my internal company network is 10.1.0.0/16 then that is my network, it is not a subnet. If I break that 10.1.0.0/16 network into smaller /24 networks then I have created subnets from that network.

If I have a 10.1.0.0/16 network and a 10.2.0.0/16 network then I have two networks, not two subnets. A subnet is a logical division of an IP network.