# Can I create IPv6 /48 addresses from IPv6 /64 block on my server? Or I need to request /48 block?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, linux-networking, ipv6

On my dedicated server and I have request from support IPv6 /48. For some reason they deliver to me IPv6 /64 like this `IPv6 /64 2001.9d2.190.846v::2` Can I build /48 addresses from the IPv6 /64? Or I need to request IPv6 /48 block from support?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does IPv6 subnetting work and how does it differ from IPv4 subnetting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting)

Comment: Can you please describe your situation more? You appear to be asking to sub-allocate a larger IPv6 block than you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use what the network admin has given to you. If it is unclear what you got (a while /64, or just a single address on a /64 subnet) or if you want more, then you should contact the network admin.

They are the authority on addresses on their network.