# AWS Elastic IPV6

Tags: ipv6, high-availability, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-ip

I posted a question some time ago about an AWS Elastic ipv6 ([AWS CLI Elastic IP, IPv6](https://serverfault.com/questions/899484/aws-cli-elastic-ip-ipv6))

Basically i need to be able to change the ipv6 from one instance to another like an elastic ip. (Instances in High Availability)

The answer that i accepted was to use: aws ec2 assign-ipv6-addresses. It did work in fact for sometime, until i created two instances in different AZ (Availability Zone). For the ipv4, Elastic IP works great. But how can i do it with ipv6?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with IPv6. I could be wrong. But remember that the addresses are assigned to _network interfaces_.

Comment: You can unassign with unassign-ipv6-addresses. But you can only assign to another network interface in the same AZ.

Comment: And i think it may be possible, since ELB do it somehow.