# IPv6 is here and confuses me

Tags: ipv6

I'm starting to get emails from various services of this kind:

```
Your gitlab.com account was signed in to from a new location
 
Hostname    gitlab.com
IP Address  2001:db8:bbbb:1:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff
Time    2020-10-30 4:32:20 PM UTC
```

In the old days, when it was just IPv4 I would recognise my own IP-address fairly quickly. This kind of notification are a lot less helpful.

Are there any tricks to find out if the IPv6 address is mine?

Is there any systematics (patterns) to IPv6 addresses that might help?

Comment: As of 2020, [the first 64 bits *typically* uniquely identify your uplink](https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting/426207#426207) so you just need to remember the first half, whereas the second half depends on whatever router manages (or leaves management to clients) your local network.

Comment: @RonMaupin TIL. Was not aware of that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP will delegate a prefix for you, probably `/48` for your business, unless you have a contract that specifies a different size. For example, `2001:db8:cafe::/48`. You will then break that prefix into separate `/64` networks. For a `/48` prefix, that means you can have 65,536 different `/64` networks: from `2001:db8:cafe::/64` to`2001:db8:cafe:ffff::/64`.

It is pretty easy to see which networks belong to you. If any of the first 48 bits delegated to you are different, e.g. `2001:db8:beef::/48`, then you would see that addressing does not belong to you.

With just a couple of exceptions, You will use `/64` networks for your IPv6. You could further subnet one or more of your `/64` network to `/127` for point-to-point links (prevents ping pong attacks) or `/128` for things like router loopbacks.