# Is SLAAC generation affected by non 64 bit size network prefix?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ip, ipv6, dhcpv6

I have enabled all the parameters needed for the generation of SLAAC, and I am obtaining router advertisement, but the network prefix in the router advertisement is /52 and not /64. The system is not getting assigned a SLAAC address. (Note that the router advertisement is in "Assisted" Mode (M+O+A flags), so that is not the issue). Should the network prefix be a /64 itself for SLAAC to be generated? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Subnet the /52 into a /64. IPv6 assumes /64 in almost all cases, and SLAAC depends on /64. A /64 should provide enough addresses for your network, so there's no need for the /52.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does IPv6 subnetting work and how does it differ from IPv4 subnetting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4862#section-5.5.3 it is specified that:

```
If the sum of the prefix length and 
interface identifier length does not
equal 128 bits, the Prefix Information
option MUST be ignored.
```

For Ethernet the interface identifier length is 64 bits, so to comply with this rule the prefix must be a /64. Any other length will be ignored for the purpose of SLAAC.